# try catch in Progress

Tags: progress-4gl

Is there a method that is similar to the try catch in php?

```
try {
    ...
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    ...
}
```

I already use the blocks of this type: `DO ON ERROR UNDO ...` but I wonder if there is another way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Since version 11.2 there's the `BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.` statement that changes the default behavior of your entire program. `CATCH` has been around longer - since version 10.1C.

```
/* Must be first line of program */
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

i = INTEGER("Hello").

CATCH err AS Progress.Lang.Error:    
    MESSAGE "Error: " err:GetMessage(1)        
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
END.
```

Older style program with do on error like your example, taken from the [Progress KnowledgeBase](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P173073?q=catch%20statement&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1).

```
DO ON ERROR UNDO, THROW:
  /* The following line raises error (138) which is diverted to a Progress.Lang.SysError object and thrown to the main block. */ 
  FIND Customer 1000.
END.
 
CATCH eAnyError AS Progress.Lang.Error:
  MESSAGE
      "Error Number:~t" eAnyError:GetMessageNum(1) "~n"
      "Error Text:~t" eAnyError:GetMessage(1)
      VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX BUTTONS OK TITLE "Error processing in the CATCH for mainprocedure block".
END CATCH.
```

**Complete description of BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW**

From the manual:

> Syntax     BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.
>
> This statement affects the following block types:
>
> Main block of an external procedure (.p)
>
> Internal procedures
>
> User-defined functions
>
> Methods of a class
>
> Class constructors
>
> Property accessors
>
> ON blocks used as database triggers with CREATE, DELETE, WRITE or
> ASSIGN events
>
> REPEAT blocks
>
> FOR blocks
>
> DO TRANSACTION blocks
>
> This statement does not affect:
> Destructors
>
> Error directives that are explicitly coded in individual, non routine-level blocks
>
> ON blocks that are UI triggers.
>
> Note these alternatives to the BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW
> statement:
> Instead of adding the statement to source-code files, you
> can use the -undothrow 2 startup parameter to change the default
> error-handling to UNDO, THROW on every block affected by the
> BLOCK-LEVEL statement during compilation. See the Startup Command and
> Parameter Reference for more information.
>
> The ROUTINE-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW statement can be used if you
> want to change the default error-handling only on routine-level
> blocks. (You can use the -undothrow 1 startup parameter to change the
> default error-handling on routine-level blocks to UNDO, THROW during
> compilation.)

Comment: Damn, I'm in 10.1B and `BLOCK-LEVEL` is not recognized. 
But I keep this answer for later. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: `THROW` and `CATCH` are not recognized either. :(

Comment: Catch as actually added in 10.1C. Too bad. 10.1B is from 2007 so an update should be considered.